# Changing from for loop to multithreading in kernel

Tags: cuda, interpolation

I'm currently working on interpolation of a grid and having some problems regarding multithreading. The code is suppose to read a map represented by a 2x2 matrix, and then interpolate it to increase the number of points by a factor of 100. When using for loops in the kernel, it works great.

Before interpolation: http://bildr.no/view/OWV1UDRO

After interpolation: http://bildr.no/view/eTlmNmpo

When I tried to change the for loops with threads, it produced some weird result. In stead of numbers, it filled the resulting matrix with -1.#QNAN

Here's my working code with for loops in the kernel

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "cuda.h"

using namespace std;

float Z[41][41];

// Macro to catch CUDA errors in CUDA runtime calls
#define CUDA_SAFE_CALL(call)                                          \
do {                                                                  \
    cudaError_t err = call;                                           \
    if (cudaSuccess != err) {                                         \
        fprintf (stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",\
                 __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err) );       \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                           \
    }                                                                 \
} while (0)

// Macro to catch CUDA errors in kernel launches
#define CHECK_LAUNCH_ERROR()                                          \
do {                                                                  \
    /* Check synchronous errors, i.e. pre-launch */                   \
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();                             \
    if (cudaSuccess != err) {                                         \
        fprintf (stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",\
                 __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err) );       \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                           \
    }                                                                 \
    /* Check asynchronous errors, i.e. kernel failed (ULF) */         \
    err = cudaThreadSynchronize();                                    \
    if (cudaSuccess != err) {                                         \
        fprintf (stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",\
                 __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString( err) );      \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                           \
    }                                                                 \
} while (0)

texture<float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> tex;


__global__ void kernel (int m, int n, float *f, float numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare) 
{
    int k = sqrt(numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare);


    for (float i=0; i<n*k; i++)
    {
        for (float j=0; j<m*k; j++) 
        {
        f[(int)(j+(m*k*i))] = tex2D (tex, j/k+0.5f, i/k+0.5f);
        }
    }

}

int main (void)
{
    // Start timer
    clock_t tStart = clock();

    // Size of map
    int n=41;
    int m=41;

    int g = 0;

    float numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare = 100;
    float numberOfElements = pow(sqrt(numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare)*n,2);

    size_t pitch, tex_ofs;
    float *f;
    float *r;
    float *map_d = 0;

    // Build read-Streams
    ifstream map;   

    //Create and open a txt file for MATLAB
    ofstream file;

    // Open data
    map.open("Map.txt", ios_base::in); 
    file.open("Bilinear.txt");

    // Store the map in a 2D array
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            map >> Z[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Allocate memory on host and device
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMallocPitch((void**)&map_d,&pitch,n*sizeof(*map_d),m));
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**)&f, numberOfElements*sizeof(float)));
    r = (float*)malloc(numberOfElements*sizeof(float));

    // Copy map from host to device
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy2D(map_d, pitch, Z, n*sizeof(Z[0][0]), n*sizeof(Z[0][0]),m,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // Set texture mode to bilinear interpolation
    tex.normalized = false;
    tex.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;

    // Bind the map to texture
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaBindTexture2D (&tex_ofs, &tex, map_d, &tex.channelDesc, n, m, pitch));

    // Checking for offset
    if (tex_ofs !=0) {
        printf ("tex_ofs = %zu\n", tex_ofs);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

    // Launch Kernel
    kernel <<< 1,1 >>> (m, n, f, numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare);
    CHECK_LAUNCH_ERROR();    
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    // Copy result from device to host
    cudaMemcpy(r, f, numberOfElements*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Write results to file
    for(int h=0;h<numberOfElements;h++)
    {
        if(g==sqrt(numberOfElements))
        {
            file << endl;
            g=0;
        }
        file << r[h] << " ";
        g++;
    }

    // Free memory
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaUnbindTexture (tex));
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaFree (map_d));
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaFree (f));
    free( r );

    // Print out execution time
    printf("Time taken: %.3fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here's the kernel with multithreading, which doesn't work

```
__global__ void kernel (int m, int n, float *f, float numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare) 
{
    int k = sqrt(numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare);

    int i= blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j= blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;


    if(i>=n*k || j>=m*k)
        return;

    f[(int)(j+(m*k*i))] = tex2D (tex, j/k+0.5f, i/k+0.5f);

}
```

Does anyone know why the multithread version doesn't work?

Regards

Sondre

Comment: If anyone would like to try the code, here's the map: http://codepad.org/fe8aWGMt

Comment: How are you launching the multithreaded kernel? Also, in the second kernel, `i` and `j` are `int` instead of `float`. So `j/k` and `i/k` in `tex2D` will result in integer division. Consider declaring `k` as `float`.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I changed the i and j to float and now it's producing some numbers, but still a lot of -1.#QNAN.

The kernel is called like this:

    // Find number of blocks
int nthreads = 1024;
int blocksize = 512;
int nblocks = ceil( (n*m*numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare) / nthreads); 

// Launch Kernel
kernel <<< nblocks,blocksize >>> (m, n, f, numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare);

Comment: You are launching 1D grid of 1D blocks, where as using 2D indexing inside the kernel. Launch 2D grid with total threads at least equal to `(m * sqrt(numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare)) x (n * sqrt(numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare))`

Comment: That make sense! Now I change the kernel launch to:  int blockSize = 512;  int gridSize = n*sqrt(numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare);  dim3 dimGrid(gridSize, gridSize);  dim3 dimBlock(blockSize, blockSize);  kernel <<< dimGrid,dimBlock >>> (m, n, f, numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare);  Now I get an error saying "invalid configuration argument"

Comment: Thats because you are launching a block of 512 x 512 which means 262144 threads per block, which is not supported by any of the current GPUs. Maximum 1024 threads per block are supported for GPUs of compute 2.0 or above. Change the `blockSize` to a valid value (e.g. 16) so total of 256 threads per block. Also you are launching very large number of blocks which is un necessary. Divide the `dimGrid` dimensions by corresponding dimensions of `dimBlock` to get exact number of blocks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, sgar91! Now it works :) One last question: When launching the kernel with <<<1,1>>>, the program takes 0.7 seconds. If I try to launch the kernel with multiple blocks and threads the execution time increases to 0.75 seconds. Shouldn't the program use less time with multiple threads?

Comment: @sgar91 if you would convert your comments to an answer I would upvote it.  Clearly you have sorted out several issues for the poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second kernel, `i` and `j` are `int` instead of `float`. So `j/k` and `i/k` in `tex2D` will result in integer division. Declare k as float to avoid integer division.

Initially, the kernel was launched with the following configuration:

```
//Find number of blocks 
int nthreads = 1024;
int blocksize = 512; 
int nblocks = ceil( (n*m*numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare) / nthreads); 

// Launch Kernel 
kernel <<< nblocks,blocksize >>> (m, n, f, numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare);
```

The problem with the above code is that it would launch a 1D grid of 1D blocks, but inside the kernel, 2D indexing is used. A 2D grid/block configuration is required for the kernel to work correctly. From the looks of the kernel code, following grid/block configuration should work:

```
float k = sqrt(numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare);

const int threads_x = (int)ceil(n * k);
const int threads_y = (int)ceil(m * k);

const dim3 dimBlock(16,16);

dim3 dimGrid;
dimGrid.x = (threads_x + dimBlock.x - 1)/dimBlock.x;
dimGrid.y = (threads_y + dimBlock.y - 1)/dimBlock.y;

kernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(m, n, f, numberOfInterpolationsPerSquare);
```